# SWD files in Flash Player 9

Tags: flash

Does anybody have any pointers to what SWD files are in Flash 9, why Flash Player wants to download them sometimes, how to make ones, how to make use of them? Didn't manage to dig anything useful myself yet.

*Update*

I know roughly what are swd files used in Flash8, and [there is even a way to make them](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/15/flex_docs_en/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Flex_Documentation&file=00000838.htm), but Flash 9 doesn't seem to need it at first glance, but still attempts to use sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

SWD files are needed to debug content with Adobe's debugging tools. You can see this in action by publishing from Flash authoring with shift-control-enter.

The SWD itself is only needed for the debugging tool to see inside the SWF. You can throw it away once you're done debugging, and you never need to upload it to the server unless you're planning to do remote debugging.

Docs:
[Debugging local files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fc0.html)
[Debugging remote files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WSE9184681-3417-4849-B487-8D6C2F8CC688.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links, shade a bit of light. However, Adobe comment in the second links says: "Only the AS2 debugger uses SWD files for debugging. They are note used for debugging AS3 files." So it's still unclear for me why flash player tries to download SWDs for pure AS3 movies.

Comment: Good point Michael, I'd forgotten that. But can you clarify what you mean about the player trying to download SWDs? Is it when you're actively trying to debug, locally or remotely, or when you're just trying to view the SWF?

Comment: Well if I put my swf online, I am getting lots of error messages in the Apache log about trying to access files like smth.swd, where smth.swf is a pure AS3/Flash9 movie. I am suspecting Flash Debug players doing that, but not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

> SWD files are similar to SWF files, except that they contain debugging-specific information that the debugger and Flash Debug Player watch for.

From: About SWD files

The citation above is from the Flex documentation but applies to 'normal' Flash too.

Comment: Backwards compatibility perhaps? If you publish as an older format?

Comment: Hm of course if you publish as an older format, but what I am seeing in the logs is:
GET /app9.swf
GET /app9.swd
where app9 is 100% pure flash9 movie. So no old format here..